# How to raise a fraction to a fractional exponent?

Tags: fractions

I am trying to simplify this but I'm not sure how to approach it.

[image]

Comment: $\left( \frac{a}{b}\right)^{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a^{\frac{c}{d}}}{b^{\frac{c}{d}}}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $\frac{1}{9} = 3^{-2}$.

Then

$\big(\frac{1}{9}\big)^{\frac{3}{2}} = 3^{-2 \cdot \frac{3}{2}} = 3^{-3} = \frac{1}{3^3} = \frac{1}{27}$.

Answer (score 2):

Try applying logarithms:

$a^b = c \implies b \ln a = \ln c$

and you also know that $1^x=1$.

Good luck!

Comment: just a dumb question why not use log base 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: this is equivalent to $\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^3}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{729}}$

Answer (score 0):

$(\frac{1}{9})^{\frac{3}{2}}=(\sqrt{\frac{1}{9}})^3=\frac{1}{27}$

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $a>0$, the following will hold:

$$a^{\frac pq}=(\sqrt[q]{a})^p.$$

In your case:

$$(\frac19)^{\frac32}=(\sqrt[2]{\frac19})^3=(\frac13)^3=\frac{1}{27}.$$

What about $a<0$? Well, if the power is defined, the above will hold.